# How to ADD 2 Tax items in an Invoice after Sub-Total to add up in Total by Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

This is my Html code in my Invoice file:

```
    <tr class="item-row">
   <td>7.</td>
   <td class="item-name">
      <input type="text" name="i7_n" placeholder="Enter Item" required="required">
   </td>
   <td class="description">
       <textarea name="i7_d" placeholder="Item Note" class="form-control"></textarea>
   </td>
   <td>
        <input  type="number" name="i7_q" step="1" min="0" class="qty">
   </td>
   <td>
        <input  type="number" name="i7_c" step="1" min="0"  class="cost">
   </td>
   <td><span class="price">0.00</span></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td colspan="3" class="blank"></td>
    <td colspan="2" class="total-line">Subtotal Rs.</td>
    <td td class="total-value"><div id="subtotal">0.00</div></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td colspan="3" class="blank"></td>
    <td colspan="2" class="total-line">CGST 2.5%</td>
    <td class="total-value"><textarea id="cgst" placeholder="%">0.00</textarea></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td colspan="3" class="blank"></td>
    <td colspan="2" class="total-line">SGST 2.5%</td>
    <td class="total-value"><textarea id="sgst" placeholder="%">0.00</textarea></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td colspan="3" class="blank"></td>
    <td colspan="2" class="total-line">Amount after GST </td>
    <td class="total-value"><div id="total">0.00</div></td>
</tr>
<tr>
     <td colspan="3" class="blank"></td>
     <td colspan="2" class="total-line">Amount Paid Rs.</td>
     <td class="total-value"><textarea id="paid">0.00</textarea></td>
</tr>
<tr>
     <td colspan="3" class="blank"></td>
     <td colspan="2" class="total-line balance">Balance Due Rs.</td>
     <td class="total-value balance"><div class="due">875.00</div></td>
</tr>
```

When i run my this following JS Code:-

```
  //This Updates subtotal & total
function update_total() {
  var total = 0;
  $('.price').each(function(i){
    price = $(this).html().replace("$","");
    if (!isNaN(price)) total += Number(price);
  });

  total = roundNumber(total,2);

  $('#subtotal').html(total);
  // $('#total').html(total);
  update_gst();
}

//this adds CGST & SGST in subtotal
function update_gst() {
  var total = $("#subtotal").html().replace("$","") + $("#cgst").val().replace("$","") + $("#sgst").val().replace("$","");
  total = roundNumber(total,2) ;
  
  $('#total').html(total);
  update_balance();
}

//this updates amount paid & outstanding at end
function update_balance() {
  var due = $("#total").html().replace("$","") - $("#paid").val().replace("$","");
  due = roundNumber(due,2);
  
  $('.due').html(due);
}

//This updates item Qty * Item Price = Item Total
function update_price() {
  var row = $(this).parents('.item-row');
  var price = row.find('.cost').val().replace("$","") * row.find('.qty').val();
  price = roundNumber(price,2);
  isNaN(price) ? row.find('.price').html("N/A") : row.find('.price').html(price);
  
  update_total();
}
```

This gives me my all balances Ok. My problem is I want to add 2 Taxes (CGST @2.5% & SGST @2.5%) [By using JS only] to Sub-Total to give Final Figures after taxes. . i think my code "update_gst()" has some issues.

Please Help me on how I can update my above JS code...

Comment: do you know the developer tools in your browser? you can set debug marker in code there and watch the values of your variables.

Comment: @jabubo can u please edit my JS... i am new in JS...

Comment: i do not know, how the form is filled. One problem might be the replacement of the $ sign in your tax-textareas where possibly a % sign will be present. Any way, when there is a percent value the formula in update_gst ist completely wrong.

Comment: `update_balance()` and the other functions work?

Comment: try using `console.log(variable_name)` in the parts of your code where the error pops and check whether the correct value is being passed

Comment: @HishamBawa yes my update_balance() and other fuctions are working,,, i have only issue in  update_gst() ... This function Not adding CGST & SGST values in subtotal to give total value...
.
Please Help me in it...